# excel formula to convert to decimals of a foot

Tags: excel

i am trying to convert a number into decimals of a foot in excel.  here is my formula

```
=IF(C2="", "",ROUND(LEFT(C2,FIND("-",C2)-2)+SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(C2,1,FIND("-",C2),""),CHAR(34),"")/12,4))
```

If Cell C2 is 41-9, it returns 4.75 
it works fine except when excel automatically changes cell c2 to a date such as 8-8.  any ideas?

Comment: You can format the cells as "Text" before entering your data to avoid the date conversion

Comment: Have you checked if there is any format settings present on the column or cell?

Answer (score 0):

Format C2 as text before you enter the value. Then it won't convert to date.

But your formula will still not work, because it does not handle single digits for the foot measure well. The single digit will result in a blank text result from the `Left()` function, which causes an error when that blank text is added to the extracted number of the Substitute bit.

Wrap an `N()` function around the `Left()`, which will turn a blank result into a zero, and then the formula works (given the cell format is text, not date).

```
=IF(C2="", "",ROUND(N(LEFT(C2,FIND("-",C2)-2))+SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(C2,1,FIND("-",C2),""),CHAR(34),"")/12,4))
```